# How to disable rollback of a substack from within cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to specify that a substack is not to be rolled back on failure when calling other CFTs from a CFT?

Ie, master CFT invoked (when invoked, you can use --disable-rollback or provide the option to CFN) -> substack 1 succesfully created -> substack 2 fails.

Now, substack 2 rolls back and I lose the record of what happened and the master CFT just sits there failed.

Is there a place to specify whether or not to allow rollback inside of a CFT, either in the invoking template (master) or the child (substack)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable the **Rollback on failure** of Cloud Formation stacks.
In the **Options** menu while creating the stack, you may find the **Advanced** portion.

[image: Options Menu]

In the expanded **Advanced** menu, you may find the **Rollback on failure** option.

[image]

Now the CFT won't rollback on failures. Even when a child stack fails It won't initiate rollback.